# Common protocols to update firmware of switches

Tags: security, switch, firmware

I had a class this morning about networking (hubs,switches etc), my teacher affirmed me that the protocol to update firmware of switches is tftp and **is secure**.

I'm surprised right now after seeing the "[Security Considerations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol#Security_Considerations)" subcategory on Wikipedia about the tftp protocol (no encryption etc)

My question is simple : What are the most common protocols to update firmware of switches ? (tftp is the only option ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFTP was designed for internal use, not for use via internet. The actual danger is opening TFTP through your firewall. So it is secure if you don't open your firewall.

On the internet side, you can make it secure through a VPN.

If you want an actual secure protocol for this, you can use SFTP. SFTP is actually based on the SSH (Secure Shell) protocol which is best known for it's use in providing secure access to shell accounts on remote servers or equipment. Some manufactures support this protocol in their switches (see the HP procurve switches as example).

Alternately, some switches can be configured to work with https and a GUI and you can use that to update their firmware.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate Security as the inverse of the Probability of Attack.

```
S=1/P(A)
```

Firmware upgrades are always (99.99% of the time) performed on non-hostile environments (or at least behind a firewall and/or NAT device), then the TFTP firmware upgrade security is very good even when the protocol itself lacks of security features.

From [RFC 7440](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7440) - TFTP Windowsize Option

```
Security Considerations

TFTP includes no login or access control mechanisms.  Care must be
taken when using TFTP for file transfers where authentication, access
control, confidentiality, or integrity checking are needed.  Note
that those security services could be supplied above or below the
layer at which TFTP runs.  Care must also be taken in the rights
granted to a TFTP server process so as not to violate the security of
the server's file system.  TFTP is often installed with controls such
that only files that have public read access are available via TFTP.
Also listing, deleting, renaming, and writing files via TFTP are
typically disallowed.  TFTP file transfers are NOT RECOMMENDED where
the inherent protocol limitations could raise insurmountable
liability concerns.

TFTP includes no protection against an on-path attacker; care must be
taken in controlling windowsize values according to data sender, data
receiver, and network environment capabilities.  TFTP service is
frequently associated with bootstrap and initial provisioning
activities; servers in such an environment are in a position to
impose device or network specific throughput limitations as
appropriate.
```

Also most of the firmware updates today use some sort of image integrity check before really flashing the binary.

The use of TFTP is classical because it is a very simple, easy to implement, protocol with a very small memory footprint.

TFTP It is also a key component on [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) network boot where the NICs use it for retrieving the NBPs and early boot components,